# MySQL changed my PATH and removed all other items I placed there. Need help reverting back

Tags: mysql, environment-variables, path

I installed MySQL some days ago on my Windows machine. Today I noticed that it modified my `PATH` to just:
 `C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Shell 8.0\bin\`

I had a lot of other items added to my `PATH` over the course of time and I lost all that. Is there any way I could revert back?

Comment: The duplicate candidate still applies to whatever version of Windows you are using.  You will have to make the changes to your PATH variable yourself.  The duplicate provides the information to restore the default PATH variable.

Comment: 1) MySQL install do not alter %PATH%. It do not use this variable at all... 2) Check system and user variables set in registry, maybe only one of them is altered 3) Try to revert your OS to restore point before %PATH% altering.

Comment: @Akina MySQL sure did add `C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Shell 8.0\bin\` to my %PATH%, and removed everything else. I just went with the default installation of MySQL.Also, quite sadly,  I do not have a restore point to which I can restore sadly.

Comment: I can confirm that MySQL was the rogue application which caused the above. I was lucky enough to have "protection" enabled for my C drive, so a system restore of - before MySQL installation fixed it and restored all the user PATH entries.